# Integrating Multiple IDPs with Okta

Tags: okta

I would like to setup Okta to use two identity providers - SAML & OpenID Connect. I would also like the users to be able to choose which IDP during the login process with one of the IDPs being the default. Has anyone implemented a custom login solution with multiple IDP's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the doc for the Okta Sign in Widget:
https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget_ref